# Pandas: search for closest preceding row in a DataFrame for a given value

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a function that when a condition is found (specifically when a column value == 'Trade') it searches back through the previous rows of two columns and finds the value that matches the trade `price`, counting the number of times the price was found in each respective column.

I have a Pandas dataframe of quote/order records:

```
import io
import pandas as pd


data_raw = """
date_time, type, price, bid_price, ask_price,
2020-11-16 01:39:06.221102501, Quote,  7045.5, 7045.0, 7047.0 
2020-11-16 01:39:06.221102501, Trade,  7045.5, 7045.0, 7047.0 
2020-11-16 01:39:06.221102501, Trade,  7045.5, 7045.0, 7047.0 
2020-11-16 01:39:09.044653308, Quote,  7045.0, 7045.0, 7046.0
2020-11-16 01:39:09.044653308, Quote,  7045.0, 7045.0, 7046.5
2020-11-16 01:39:09.044653308, Quote,  7045.0, 7045.0, 7046.0
2020-11-16 01:39:09.044653308, Quote,  7045.0, 7045.0, 7046.0
2020-11-16 01:39:09.824195125, Quote,  7045.0, 7045.0, 7046.0
2020-11-16 01:39:09.824195125, Quote,  7045.0, 7045.0, 7046.5
2020-11-16 01:39:09.824195125, Quote,  7045.0, 7045.0, 7046.0
2020-11-16 01:39:09.984520580, Quote,  7045.0, 7045.0, 7046.0
2020-11-16 01:39:10.408151534, Quote,  7045.0, 7045.0, 7046.0
2020-11-16 01:39:10.564184018, Quote,  7045.0, 7045.0, 7046.0
2020-11-16 01:39:11.008204633, Quote,  7045.0, 7045.0, 7046.0
2020-11-16 01:39:11.032939855, Quote,  7045.0, 7045.0, 7046.0
2020-11-16 01:39:11.230065390, Quote, 7045.0, 7044.0,  7046.0
2020-11-16 01:39:11.230065390, Trade,  7045.0, 7044.0, 7046.0
2020-11-16 01:39:11.232176362, Quote,  7045.0, 7044.0, 7045.5
2020-11-16 01:39:12.924164557, Quote,  7045.0, 7044.0, 7046.0
"""

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data_raw), sep=",")
df
```

I want to create two separate columns that are the cumulative sum of the number of times a trade matches the nearest **preceding** quote on the `bid_price` column or the `ask_price` column. I suspect I will need to create a function to achieve this.

For example when the record `type` is 'Trade', and the price is 7040.0, I want the function to search back through the previous n records and find a matched quote. If the price matches on the 'bid_price' then I can += 1 the count of bids and vice versa if it matches on the 'ask_price'.

I have tried setting the 'date_time' column as an index and sorting chronologically, however, the trades don't always immediately follow a quote.

My initial thoughts is to use something like `pd.index.get_loc(df['price'], method='ffill', tolerance=10)` however, I cannot work out how to then search the separate `bid_price` or `ask_price` columns?

Expected output:

```
date_time                     type  price  bid_price ask_price cum_bid cum_ask
2020-11-16 01:39:06.221102501 Quote 7045.5 7045.0    7047.0    0       0
2020-11-16 01:39:06.221102501 Trade 7045.5 7045.0    7047.0    1       0
2020-11-16 01:39:06.221102501 Trade 7045.5 7045.0    7047.0    2       0
2020-11-16 01:39:09.044653308 Quote 7045.0 7045.0    7046.0    2       0
2020-11-16 01:39:09.044653308 Quote 7045.0 7045.0    7046.5    2       0
2020-11-16 01:39:09.044653308 Quote 7045.0 7045.0    7046.0    2       0
2020-11-16 01:39:09.044653308 Quote 7045.0 7045.0    7046.0    2       0
2020-11-16 01:39:09.824195125 Quote 7045.0 7045.0    7046.0    2       0
2020-11-16 01:39:09.824195125 Quote 7045.0 7045.0    7046.5    2       0
2020-11-16 01:39:09.824195125 Quote 7045.0 7045.0    7046.0    2       0
2020-11-16 01:39:09.984520580 Quote 7045.0 7045.0    7046.0    2       0
2020-11-16 01:39:10.408151534 Quote 7045.0 7045.0    7046.0    2       0     
2020-11-16 01:39:10.564184018 Quote 7045.0 7045.0    7046.0    2       0
2020-11-16 01:39:11.008204633 Quote 7045.0 7045.0    7046.0    2       0
2020-11-16 01:39:11.032939855 Quote 7045.0 7045.0    7046.0    2       0
2020-11-16 01:39:11.230065390 Quote 7045.0 7044.0    7046.0    2       0
2020-11-16 01:39:11.230065390 Trade 7045.0 7044.0    7046.0    3       0
2020-11-16 01:39:11.232176362 Quote 7045.0 7044.0    7045.5    3       0
2020-11-16 01:39:12.924164557 Quote 7045.0 7044.0    7046.0    3       0
```

Any help gratefully received, thank you.

Comment: can you post an expected output for that dataframe

Comment: @Kenan Added the expected output now.

Comment: the expected output df is different from the input df in the price column, is that correct?

Comment: @Kenan Yes it is - the output dataframe is contrived. It is to demonstrate how I would like the two output columns to perform.

Comment: I thought we were  only creating the `cum_bid/cum_ask` columns, how is the price column recalculated? There are 2 trades in the input df and 3 in the expected output

Comment: sorry - i think the expected output confused things. I have changed it to reflect the input dataframe. `Price` is static, not calculated, as it is the price a contract exchanged for following a quote. I need the two columns, `cum_bid` and `cum_ask` to count the number of times a trade exchanged at `bid_price` and `ask_price`. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Backfill the price columns

`df['price'] = df['price'].bfill()`

Check where it equals the bid/ask column, calculate the cumsum and filter with the trade column

```
df['cum_ask'] = df['price'].eq(df['ask_price']).cumsum().where(df['type'].eq(' Trade'), None).ffill()

df['cum_bid'] = df['price'].eq(df['bid_price']).cumsum().where(df['type'].eq(' Trade'), None).ffill()
```

Final clean up created nans

`df[['cum_bid', 'cum_ask']] = df[['cum_bid', 'cum_ask']].fillna(0).astype(int)`

```
                        date_time    type   price  bid_price  ask_price  cum_ask  cum_bid
0   2020-11-16 01:39:06.221102501   Quote  7045.5     7045.0     7047.0        0        0
1   2020-11-16 01:39:06.221102501   Trade  7045.5     7045.0     7047.0        0        0
2   2020-11-16 01:39:06.221102501   Trade  7045.5     7045.0     7047.0        0        0
3   2020-11-16 01:39:09.044653308   Quote  7045.0     7045.0     7046.0        0        0
4   2020-11-16 01:39:09.044653308   Quote  7045.0     7045.0     7046.5        0        0
5   2020-11-16 01:39:09.044653308   Quote  7045.0     7045.0     7046.0        0        0
6   2020-11-16 01:39:09.044653308   Quote  7045.0     7045.0     7046.0        0        0
7   2020-11-16 01:39:09.824195125   Quote  7045.0     7045.0     7046.0        0        0
8   2020-11-16 01:39:09.824195125   Quote  7045.0     7045.0     7046.5        0        0
9   2020-11-16 01:39:09.824195125   Quote  7045.0     7045.0     7046.0        0        0
10  2020-11-16 01:39:09.984520580   Quote  7045.0     7045.0     7046.0        0        0
11  2020-11-16 01:39:10.408151534   Quote  7045.0     7045.0     7046.0        0        0
12  2020-11-16 01:39:10.564184018   Quote  7045.0     7045.0     7046.0        0        0
13  2020-11-16 01:39:11.008204633   Quote  7045.0     7045.0     7046.0        0        0
14  2020-11-16 01:39:11.032939855   Quote  7045.0     7045.0     7046.0        0        0
15  2020-11-16 01:39:11.230065390   Quote  7045.0     7044.0     7046.0        0        0
16  2020-11-16 01:39:11.230065390   Trade  7045.0     7044.0     7046.0        0       12
17  2020-11-16 01:39:11.232176362   Quote  7045.0     7044.0     7045.5        0       12
18  2020-11-16 01:39:12.924164557   Quote  7045.0     7044.0     7046.0        0       12
```

Comment: Thank you for this - the logic seems very sound however the cumsum() is exhibiting strange behaviour. When I apply this to the entire dataframe, the cum count for both columns, `cum_ask` and `cum_bid` counts don't tally with the number of trades? Also, I am unsure where you arrive at `df[['bcum','acum']]` as we did not create any columns with those names?

Comment: updated, please update the question with the sample df that's giving an issue and ill update the logic

Comment: no, i meant replace the current example with the problematic one and also post the expected output

Comment: the expected output is the same - no change. I have updated the current example, however.

Comment: I think your expected output is wrong, for index 1 why is `cum_bid == 1`, the `price == 7045.5` which  != `bid_price == 7045.0`

Comment: yes you are right - I have cum_bid and cum_ask columns the wrong way round.

Comment: That still doesn't seem correct, I don't understand why `cum_ask==1` at `index == 1` when the `price != cum_ask`.i updated my post with what I believe is the correct expected output

Comment: I can see the error - there is no associated quote with the first trade. In your output, the cum_bid at index == 16 should == 1, and not == 12, as there has been one trade associated with a quote on the bid_price at index == 14? so cumulatively, one contract sold? Thank you.

Comment: the `bid_price` is the same from index [0-14] so shouldn't that be cumulative summed? I feel like  I still don't fully understand the logic here; however I believe I gave you enough help for you to take it from here

Comment: thank you for your help. I might simply rethink the question and try a different approach. I have tried multiple variants, many of which include your logic. The foundation of the question lies predominantly in finding a nearest neighbour.